# How do I call a model method in django ModelAdmin fieldsets?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to display an embedded map on an admin form when data already exists in the db. I have the following code:

models.py

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField()

    def address_2_html(self):
        if self.address:
            # Return html for an embedded map using the entered address.
            return embedded_map_html
        else:
            return ''
    address_2_html.allow_tags = True
```

admin.py

```
class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [(label, {'fields': ['address','address_2_html']}),]
```

This doesn't work.  I get an error:

```
'AddressAdmin.fieldsets[1][1]['fields']' refers to field 'address_2_html' that is missing from the form.
```

Another thing I tried was using the 'description' option for 'fieldsets', however, 'address_2_html' is not accessible within the scope of AddressAdmin.  I did succeed at embedding a static map using 'description' which was cool but not cool enough.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like that (from memory):

```
class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [(label, {'fields': ['address','address_2_html']}),]
    readonly_fields = ['address_2_html']

    def address_2_html(self, obj):
        return obj.address_2_html()
    address_2_html.allow_tags = True
    address_2_html.short_description = 'Address display'
```

Comment: I get the following error with this solution: 'AddressAdmin.fieldsets[0][1]['fields']' refers to field 'address_2_html' that is missing from the form.

Comment: If 'display_map3' is equivalent to your 'address_2_html' in your example, did you put 'display_map3' in `readonly_fields` like in my example?

Comment: That solution does work for 'list_display' but not 'fieldsets'.

Comment: It works for me in `fieldsets`. There's something wrong elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Adding the readonly_fields = ['address_2_html'] option helped. It works now. I like your solution much better than overriding the get_fieldsets(). Thanks.

Comment: For Django 1.9 & +, use `return format_html(...)` instead of `.allow_tags = True`, [since deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/).

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by overriding get_fieldsets() since the get_fieldsets() method allows access to the model object Address.

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    fs = [
        (self.label,  {'fields': ['address',]}),
        ('Map', {'fields': [], # required by django admin
                'description':obj.address_2_html(),
         }),
    ]
    return fs
```