# Adding fields from another model into admin inlines - Django admin

Tags: python, django

Consider this:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ('Field1', {'fields': ['field1']}),
        ('Field2', {'fields': ['field2']}),
        ...
        ]
    list_display = ('field1', 'field2')
```

Let's say I have another model for my admin:

```
@admin.register(AnotherModel)
AnotherModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ('Field1', {'fields': ['field3']}),
        ('Field2', {'fields': ['field4']}),
        ...
        ]
    list_display = ('field3', 'field4')
```

So, I need to show `field3` from `AnotherModelAdmin` into `MyModelAdmin` inlines.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Here is how you should do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778274/186202

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a model method in django ModelAdmin fieldsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777989/how-do-i-call-a-model-method-in-django-modeladmin-fieldsets)

Comment: But this is not a method is a different class

Comment: You can create a function that would display the field of the other model, what would prevent it?

Comment: Hi, thank you, I was just thinking about that, but there are many ways to accomplish it, I'm a little thick in my mind, do you have any simple example that works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like that?

```
class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [("User", {'fields': ['user_address']}),]
    readonly_fields = ['user_address']

    def user_address(self, obj):
        return obj.user.address
    user_address.short_description = 'User address'
```

Or maybe you are want to actually change the content of the another model field.
In that case you can use something like that: [How to create a UserProfile form in Django with first_name, last_name modifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727564/how-to-create-a-userprofile-form-in-django-with-first-name-last-name-modificati)